# SIZE_t type in cython on sklearn source code

Tags: scikit-learn, cython

I tried to implement a subset of sklearn's Criterion object based on this:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_criterion.pyx#L54.

However, when I tried to run the code in my jupyter notebook, it gets an error saying
**TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()** and there are some `**^**` pointer that points to my type of parameters in the init function as below:

```
cdef int init(self, const DOUBLE_t[:, ::1] y, DOUBLE_t* sample_weight,
                  double weighted_n_samples, SIZE_t* samples, 
                  SIZE_t start, SIZE_t end):
```

I tried to change the type ***SIZE_t into size_t*** and ***DOUBLE_t into double***, and the errors are gone. But I am not sure why does the source code have SIZE_t and DOUBLE_t in it, and if it is safe to just use size_t and double as types in my code. Thanks.

Probably this has some relationship to C types, but I am not sure.

Comment: You must also take PCs file into account https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_criterion.pxd However, using a setup.py is a better way than misusing Cython-magic here - magic is gods for ad-hoc modules, not the more complicated ones

Comment: I mean pxd-file...